# I cannot connect to azure devops artifacts - nuget feed

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, nuget-package

I cannot connect to my nuget feed by visual studio 2017 enterprise. I'm owner of nuget feed. When I use browser in VS i can connect but when i use nuget source i get 401 unauthorized exception.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyZAQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Does your organization connect to AAD? Do you use a Work account or Microsoft account?

If your organization doesn’t connect to AAD, and you use a work account, you’ll meet this error. If you use a MSA account, you’ll find you can restore the packages without issue.

It’s a known issue, and has been fixed in VS 2019 Preview2 (I have verified it’s working in VS2019 Preview2). Currently, the workaround for previous versions of VS is generating a PAT and register the Nuget feed on your system with following command. I’ve tested in VS2017, after running the command below, I can restore the package with a work account:

```
nuget.exe sources Add -Name "FeedName" -Source "https://feedurl" -username unused -password PAT
```